# formal grammar from automaton

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, finite-automata, formal-grammar

Given this automaton $M=(Q,δ,q0,F)$ over alphabet Σ={a,p}Σ={a,p}:
[image]

Find a regular grammar $G=( N,Σ,P,S)$ s.t. T(M)=L(G)

I found this grammar and I would know if is correct: G=( N,Σ,P,S) where:

N=Q

S=$q_0$

P=$\{q_0 \rightarrow aq_o|pq_1|a|p$

$q_1 \rightarrow aq_2|pq_1|a|p$

$q_2 \rightarrow aq_o|pq_3|a|p$

$q_3 \rightarrow aq_4|pq_1|p$

$q_4 \rightarrow aq_4|pq_4 \}$

Moreover, I would know if is formally correct delete $q4$ productions (and productions where $q4$ appears) since $q4$ is a trap state and doesn't generate words of L:

$P-(\{q_4 \rightarrow aq_4|p_q4\} \cup \{q_3 \rightarrow aq_4\})$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add $q_0\to\lambda$ (or $q_0\to\epsilon$, depending on your symbol for the empty word), but otherwise it seems to be okay. And yes, you can delete every production that mentions $q_4$.

Comment: To go further than @BrianM.Scott, I think the easiest is to have the rule $q\to \epsilon$ for every accepting $q$ instead of having $q\to a$ when there is a transition reading $a$ from $q$ to an accepting state. This way you don't have to worry when the initial state is accepting (which is the reason Brian made his comment)